# How do you make an end-capped gear cable?

Tags: gears, internally-geared-hub, cable

I want to make my own gear cable of non-standard length. I have a cable with one end capped like the larger end-cap shown in the first picture; the other end is currently bare — I have trimmed the cable to the right length.

I need to create an end-cap on the bare end of the cable (after sliding through the ferrule), similar to the thinner end-cap in the first diagram.

I have considered using the standard 1.6 mm cable caps but these aren't not going to work because:

- I need a slender and well-rounded end-cap to fit inside the ferrule
- A pinched cable tip fails because the force of a gear change is applied directly to the anchor (and it just gets torn off)

[image]

How are these end-capped cables manufactured and therefore how can I make my own?

My specific ferrule and indicator are here:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need anchors on both ends?  Typically you have an anchor on the lever end the other end the cable is pinched with a nut and then you just have cap on the cable end to keep it from fraying. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The ferrule has a thread that screws on to a hub gear indicator

Comment: Please provide a picture of your hub gear indicator and ferrule with threads.

Comment: I've now provided a photo of my ferrule and indicator

Comment: Oh, much more clear. I you look up into the threads if it restricts then hopefully find a cable with an anchor that small - even if you had to file it.  Otherwise solder the ferrule to the cable.  You need more than crimp for an anchor - an end cap is just to stop fraying.

Comment: My question remains, how do I make an anchor?

Comment: It is not clear that ferrule is even designed to attach via an anchor - more likely that ferrule is (was) an anchor. You want to make an anchor from scratch?  Create a mold, pour in liquid metal, and let it harden.  Sorry I could not help.  Those end caps in the first picture are not anchors.

Comment: I've ammended to language in the question to make it clear I'm looking to make the end-caps on the cable. I had thought these were called anchors.

Comment: End cap and anchors are different thing that go on the end. An end cap just stops fraying and will pull off.  Why you want to manufacture your own anchor is beyond me?  I will leave you alone.

Comment: I am doubtful that you need a factory anchor on both ends.  I can't imagine a shift cable being designed that way, especially on such an old bike.  I would guess that there's some way to lock a cable into the "ferrule" without a factory end.

Comment: (A common trick is two beads.  You put both beads on the cable, then bend the cable around and fish the end back through the bead placed on the cable first.  Pull tight and you have a fairly strong lock.  Similar things are done with small metal plates with holes in them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of industry solutions for crimping stops on to a cable like this.  They sometimes require a special crimp tool, but you can usually get by with a vice.

You might start with something like this:

http://www.savacable.com/pages/prod_02_04.html

See the second entry, "Stop Sleeves"

Answer (score 3):

If this is a 3 speed Sturmey Archer or similar system you need a replacement cable. It will come complete with the cable and housing with the ends installed. There are universal replacement cables available (I have one on my 35 year old Raleigh). The shift adjuster ferrule has a clamp/pinch nut attached so a standard shift cable can be used. Checking several on line retailers shows most of the replacement cables (non NOS) use this universal setup